# css border-radius renders differently in desktop (chrome) and android

Tags: android, cordova, css

I want to implement the following pie chart on a phonegap application:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/betEm

But, on the Android browser (phonegap) the chart is rendered like this:

[image: chart on android webview]

Similar issue happens with the (.)spinner as well.

It looks to me that this property

```
 border-radius: 100% 0 0 100% / 50% 0 0 50%;
```

is the one rendered diffrently in our desktop browsers and the android one.

Comment: PS: I ended up using images